# Vue.js custom directive accessing context of a loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
Vue.directive("custom", {
    inserted(el, binding, vnode) {
        let val = binding.value;
        let arg = binding.arg
        let mods = binding.modifiers
        let expr = binding.expression
        let cont = vnode.context
        .... // modify loop
    }
})
```

I am attempting to build a custom directive in vue.  this directive can be fire inside or outside of a v-for loop.  When it is fired inside the v-for loop I need the context of the current iteration

```
v-for="item in list"  // i need the context for item
```

But I am at a loss of how to get it.  even if used the version of v-for that included the index

```
v-for="(item, index) in list"  // i need the context for item
```

neither of these values are accessible in the the directive insert function.  At least I cannot find them anywhere.

Any help locating these values would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

> Directive hooks are passed these arguments:
>
> el: The element the directive is bound to. This can be used to
> binding: An object containing the
> following properties. 
>  ... 
> value: The value passed to the directive. For example in
> v-my-directive="1 + 1", the value would be 2.

And you have it here already

```
let val = binding.value;
```

You just need to pass it to the directive.

```
<div v-for="item in list" :v-custom="item"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't help if you're looking to make a more general directive that should work out of the box, for example, how would you duplicate the functionality of `v-model`? It knows about for loop context but the context is not explicitly passed into the directive.

Comment: Consider this example `v-model="someArray[forLoopItem]"`. `v-model` needs to know the value of `forLoopItem` in order to update the model when the input emits the "input" event.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `value` in the `binding` [directive hook argument](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments).

For example in `v-custom="item"`, the `value` would be the `item`.

```
Vue.directive("custom", {
    inserted(el, binding, vnode) {
        let val = binding.value; // this value is the item
        let arg = binding.arg
        let mods = binding.modifiers
        let expr = binding.expression
        let cont = vnode.context
        .... // modify loop
    }
})
```

Example (see log):

```js
Vue.directive("custom", {
  inserted(el, binding, vnode) {
    let val = binding.value;
    let arg = binding.arg
    let mods = binding.modifiers
    let expr = binding.expression
    let cont = vnode.context

    console.log(val)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [{
        text: "Learn JavaScript",
        done: false
      },
      {
        text: "Learn Vue",
        done: false
      },
      {
        text: "Play around in JSFiddle",
        done: true
      },
      {
        text: "Build something awesome",
        done: true
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo) {
      todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos" v-custom="todo">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          v-on:change="toggle(todo)"
          v-bind:checked="todo.done">

        <del v-if="todo.done">
          {{ todo.text }}
        </del>
        <span v-else>
          {{ todo.text }}
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```